# Some Help Please with ( Function sendEmail )

Tags: powershell

can some body help me to solve this one,
I can't understand where i need to put my mail parameters, smtp server and so.

THIS IS THE SCRIPT:

```
Function sendEmail 
{ param($from,$to,$subject,$smtphost,$htmlFileName) 
$body = Get-Content $htmlFileName 
$smtp= New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient $smtphost 
$msg = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $from, $to, $subject, $body 
$msg.isBodyhtml = $true 
$smtp.send($msg) 

}
```

Comment: Most probably in `$from,$to,$subject,$smtphost,$htmlFileName`...

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're still using PowerShell v1 (which you shouldn't) use [`Send-MailMessage`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx) instead of [`System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) and [`System.Net.Mail.MailMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx):

```
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtphost `
  -To $to `
  -From $from `
  -Subject $subject `
  -Body (Get-Content $htmlFileName | Out-String) `
  -BodyAsHtml
```

Comment: If you're using V3, you can also use the -Raw switch on Get-Content

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I'm understanding you correctly but, I think you're struggling with actually using your function, because that script is fine.

As already pointed out Send-MailMessage is easier to work with than the .net stuff.

If you want to call your function from the shell, first you have to import it

```
Import-Module sendemail.ps1
```

Then you can call it from your shell by filling in the parameters.